# Airflow : Download latest file from S3 with Wildcard

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, airflow

Requirement: To download the latest file i.e., current file from s3

Sample file in s3

```
bucketname/2020/09/reporting_2020_09_20200902000335.zip
bucketname/2020/09/reporting_2020_09_20200901000027.zip
```

When I pass the s3_src_key as `/2020/09/reporting_2020_09_20200902` doesn't work for below one

Code:

```
 with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('r') as f_source, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w') as f_target:
     s3_client.download_file(self.s3_src_bucket, self.s3_src_key, f_source.name)
```

Below one works fine

```
import os
bucket = 'bucketname'
key = '/2020/09/reporting_2020_09_20200902'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)
objects = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key)
for obj in objects:
    path, filename = os.path.split(obj.key)
    my_bucket.download_file(obj.key, filename)
```

I need help how to use wildcard in Airflow

Comment: I guess you would iterate over the objects in the bucket, sort them by date extracted from the filename, and then pick the first one.

Comment: How do you define "latest file"? Would you base it on the `LastModified` date that indicates when the object was stored in Amazon S3, or are you basing it on an interpretation of the filename? If you are using the filename, what is the rule for finding the "latest file", given the folder name and filename (Key)? Will it always say `reporting_`? Also, why is the year+month listed 3 times (`2020/09`, `2020_09` and `202009`)? What if they disagree with each other?

Comment: That's how the vendor is sending files :) .. Yes I get reporting_ files, based on filename example here `reporting_2020_09_20200902` is todays file .I can also go by LastModifiedDate too But I thought prefix with filename is easier one

Answer (score 0):

You can list objects that match a given pattern, but then you'll need to write code that decides which one of them is the latest.

Here's the [Python SDK function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2) you'll need